# Handle #import (tlh) when building c++ with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm changing the build system for our application to use cmake.
We have C++ files with #import (generating .tlh when compiled) which must be built before the other source files and I haven't found any way to specify the dependencies in the *CMakeLists.txt*.

Specifying the intermediate files directory (where the .obj are located) would solve my problem.

Thank you

We have cpp files with #import:

```
#import <xxx.dll> no_namespace raw_interfaces_only
```

The import results in an include file .tlh when compiling the cpp with the import statement, other cpp are including the generated .tlh file which creates dependencies between the cpp source files.

Comment: What are you trying to import exactly?  Why would the files with #import need to be compiled before all other sources files for the target? Is it because one source file uses #import and the others use #include for the tlh file?

Comment: CMake will determine the dependencies (and the build order), when you are linking the libraries to the targets.

Answer (score 3):

This has gone unanswered for a long time, but hopefully this solution can help others. The approach is to build an import library which generates the tlh file. Dependent libraries or applications can reference this library, which will include the binary directory where the tlh is produced.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

# Compile file containing #import statement, which will produce tlh files in build directory
add_library(import STATIC import.cpp)
target_include_directories(import PUBLIC 
    $<$<CONFIG:Release>: ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/import.dir/Release>
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>: ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/import.dir/Debug>
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/import.dir/src   # Ninja
)
# Ninja needs to have a dependency on the tlh file produced when compiling import.cpp above
# This is a fake step to satisfy Ninja. Hackish, but I couldn't find another way to specify this relationship
add_custom_target(generate_tlh
    BYPRODUCTS 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/import.dir/src/msado.tlh
    COMMAND echo "generating tlh dependency"
)
add_dependencies(generate_tlh import)

project(example)
add_executable(example
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/import.dir/src/msado.tlh
    main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example import)
add_dependencies(example generate_tlh) # forces example to wait for import library to finish
```

import.cpp

```
#import <c:\program files\common files\system\ado\msado28.tlb> no_namespace rename("EOF","adoEOF")
void stub() {}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <msado28.tlh>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{}
```